# Electron : can not find module jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, electron

I am trying to use jQuery and bootstrap in my electron project

I want to use them like :

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery') 
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap')
```

each of these lines give me an error :

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
```

or

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'bootstrap'
```

But when I check in my node modules directory I can see both bootstrap and jquery folders

Also I can find this path in environment variable and also in node (module.paths)

I tried any kind of installation like :

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install jquery --save-dev
npm install jquery -g
```

Still I am getting this error and I don't know why

When I use nodejs in command line like this :

```
>>>node
>require('bootstrap')
Thrown:
{ Error: Cannot find module 'popper.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at C:\Users\Majidi\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js:7:102 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your module require statement isn't working for some reason but the other alternative to adding Bootstrap, Popper, and jQuery through Node.js modules is just using the CDN in the HTML file.

This should work fine: (make sure to include in the `<head>` tag of your renderer .html file)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

These snippets are from the [Bootstrap getting started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/) page.

Also make sure to put the `<script>` tags for your own JS files **AFTER** the snipped above to properly use jQuery.